# How to send and receive an object from PC to an Android Device

Tags: android

I am getting trouble in sending and receiving an objects From Pc to An Android device.
I tried using `ObjectInputStream`, but I wasn't able to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless you supply the code you're trying to use then it's difficult for anyone to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to copy a file from PC to android.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

See copyDataBase() . In this example, the user is copying a db file (not database *per se*) to android as a file. So same trick should work for you.

Make sure you are copying content to your package